# Show Mysql table elements as pages in Wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, mysql, sql

I am trying to build a WordPress site, but I need a specific functionality and I haven't been able to find a plugin for it.

I'm going to be scraping sites info and posting the info into a DB (this is already handled). But, I want to create a page to display an index of all of the info, and then have a unique page to display each individual element (row of the ddbb table).

Any ideas how to achieve this??

Comment: Are there any specific reasons you're wanting to use WordPress? If you already have the code built out, it sounds like creating the site a different way might be easiest. If you really want to use WP, it is probably worth revisiting your current code and updating it so that instead of storing the information in the current database, you use WP functions like `wp_insert_post()` so you can use all of WP's built-in capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, create custom post type to store info. You do not need to create any custom table as your every record will be saved as a unique post in your custom post type. For detailed assistance, please have a look at the documentation here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Let us know if there is any confusion. We would love to help.